# External js is not working in django

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to load external js file
settings for static folder

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Here I include js in template

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
<link type="text/javascript" href="{% static '/js/main.js' %}">
```

And my project structure

```
-project
---app
---static
-----css
-------main.css
-----js
-------main.js
```

I dont know why, but css works and js is not loaded (I don't see main.js in the browser developer tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the script tag for js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

There is a difference with setting STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS. STATIC_ROOT is the location where static files are compiled to.

You should set `STATICFILES_DIRS` to

```
(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

and STATIC_ROOT to some other location where you want compiled staticfiles to live, say, `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist')`

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: It was script at first, same result

Comment: Ok, i replaced link to script again and now it works.